# WooCommerce: How can I get orders with a custom ID in order meta data object?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, serialization, woocommerce

Because of a project I need help from you. I've searched a lot but I can't find a solution.
I'm trying to edit a WooCommerce function named

- > woocommerce_account_orders

---

I've added the field

- > mycustom_id

to the the orders meta-data object because I need to get all orders which has the current logged in user in the field mycustom_id:

- > (mycustom_id = current_user_id())

---

The check for the `customer` should stay. I just need to add this other `current_user_id` check.

This sould stay as it is:

- > 'customer' => get_current_user_id()

---

. This is my not working code snippet:

```
function woocommerce_account_orders( $current_page ) {
    $current_page    = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page );
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
        'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
        'mycustom_id' => get_current_user_id(),
        'page'     => $current_page,
        'paginate' => true,
    ) ) );

    wc_get_template(
        'myaccount/orders.php',
        array(
            'current_page'    => absint( $current_page ),
            'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
            'has_orders'      => 0 < $customer_orders->total,
        )
    );
}
```

The method is located in: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_account_orders.html#2465-2486

---

How can I add this feature to the function a smart way like a filter and how can I pass my custom parameter the right way to the function? I've saved the parameter as an order_meta attribute:

```
[5] => WC_Meta_Data Object (
     [current_data:protected] => Array (
          [id] => 3477
          [key] => mycustom_id
          [value] => 2
)
```

Thank you for your help. I've tried so much but I'm new in PHP and must lurn a lot..

Comment: Is there no one who can help me? Is this to crazy to do? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change this query you can do it by calling the `woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query` filter instead of modifying the core function so you can achieve the required desired as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'modify_my_order_query', 10, 1 );

function modify_my_order_query( $q ) {
    $q['customer'] = [ 1, 3 ]; // you customers ids here 

    return $q;
}
```

but this function above will display the order in the list only and if the customer click on that order to see the details he will got an error message as he doesn't  have the permission to view the order and you need to modify the `view_order` capability

for example you can give the user with ID 1 permission to view user ID 3 orders as follow:

```
function give_permissions( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {
    $user = 3; //user id 
    if ( $cap[0] == 'view_order' ) {
        $allcaps[ $cap[0] ] = true;
    }
    return ( $allcaps );
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'give_permissions', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: The point is that I need to implement a "share order" function so if my custom id is set to an other user, he should see the order from original customer too. So that's why I've implemented the custom field to save the id from the second user. Your function just returns all orders for customer 1 and 3 right? So this is not working for me :/ Because of this I need to modify the original function this way with my custom id.

Comment: @Johnny97 if you store your customer id in the database you can merge the custom customer id  with `get_current_user_id`  the idea above is to give you a hint of how you can start to achieve your target

Comment: And how should I set 2 customer ids to one order? I mean it would be easier to check the parameter in each order or not?

Comment: I save the second customer id as an order meta field in each order. For example order A was bought by user 1 and I want to show this order to user 2, I set 2 to my custom field. So I need to change the function where the orders are get to check if this field has a value. If this is true, I must show the order to customer 2 too.

Comment: in this case you dont need to merge as you already stored in them as array you just to get those id's  from db by using get_post_meta function

Comment: This is what I've tried in my code snippet but I don't works. This is the original WooCommerce function which returns all orders for a customer in the Orders section in the account. I know how to get my meta value from the order object because I already did that to set it but now I'm struggling with the original WooCommerce function. Do you know how to change the function to check the custom parameter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181166/discussion-between-kashalo-and-johnny97).